# How to determine a rectangle position?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas

I'm currently working at a puzzle game in Javascript that is made using a HTML canvas element.
When a user chooses to drag a piece, I redraw the canvas each time based on its movement. Now, when user deselects the puzzle piece, I want to determine which pieces should be switched.

[piece draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgCd4.png)

So in the picture above I draw a small schema of what I want to accomplish. When user drags the first piece until the position marked with red I want to switch piece 1 with piece 9.

For all the three pieces piece1, piece9 and moving piece I know: x,y coordinates and both width and height.

My question is: How can I determine which piece I should switch the moving one with, because the new position of piece 1 has common points with pieces 5, 6, 8 and 9?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us your HTML and JavaScript code so far.

Comment: @varlogtim my question has nothing to do with that one. I know the coordinates of each rectangle I draw.

Comment: The easiest solution is to draw your dragged cell so that its center is at the mouse coordinates, then you just have to get which cell your cursor is hover (in your example cell 9) https://jsfiddle.net/wqfwarop/